# Does anyone know what this diagram could be about?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, visualization, big-picture

Does anyone know what this diagram could be about? I found it about a year ago on some blog and I tried to relocate the source of the picture but was unable to.

My best guess is that maybe $R(x)$ and $G(x)$ are ring-like structures, $\mathfrak{D}^*_x$ and $\mathfrak{D}_x$ are some operators, $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$ are morphisms, and $s_0,t_0$ are elements in some space or initial objects. I don't know what the thing in the middle is: $\mathscr{M[g,x;p]}$ which would probably help a lot. Maybe it could represent a moduli space parametrized by $\mathscr p$ with $\mathscr g$ as some metric and $\mathscr x$ as some variable?

> Is this a valid category theory diagram, and does my guess make sense at a "high level?"

[image]

Comment: Without some real context it is practicaly impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @Somos that's why I put the tag "soft question." All I know is that the blog was in the scope of category theory and algebraic geometry.